# Backbone.js : What's the correct way of using the latest Backbone routes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm running into a few issues with the latest Backbone.js release 0.9.0. It includes some changes to its routes component. One of the confusing ones is the removal of "leading slashes". There is a discussion on GitHub https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/848.

With the previous version, I would do

```
routes:
  "" : "search"
  "search/:type/:keywords" : "search"
```

And that would handle all types of scenarios including

```
search/a/b
search//b (when a is null or empty)
search/a/
```

But now I have to do

```
routes:
  "" : "search"
  "search/:type"  : "search"
  "search/:type/" : "search"
  "search/:type/:keywords" : "search"
  "search/:type/:keywords/" : "search"
```

In order to make sure different combinations of URL parameters are handled properly.

I understand their rationale on removing this and in that case, am I implementing this correctly? I seem to "over-work" on something that was easily and well handled in the previous version.

Comment: I was having trouble with my routes with 0.9 as well. There has been an update to 0.9.1 that helped me out.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll have to try this.